# MPAndroidChart how to draw y-axis limit line and set view point to bottom

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

MPAndroidChart is very awesome library.I am very thankful to.
But now, I have 3 problems.

The version I used is...

```
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.5'
```

And my problem is,...

Left: now -> Right: want to be
[image]

**1.
How to draw limit a Y value line on line chart or bar chart?**

e.g. I want to draw value y=200 line on Image.
(e.g. attached image top.shown in red)

**2.
How to set viewpoint to bottom and get y-axis mint limit to bottom value?**
(e.g. attached image bottom)
I want to set viewpoint to bottom.
I tried this code ,But still,there is some padding.

```
    XAxis xAxis = mBarChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setAxisMinValue(0);
```

I want to trim this padding.

***Edited**

This works well. Thank you!

```
    mChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinValue(0);
```

**3.How to remove point of graph on line chart?**

A line chart, the bottom image, has lots of marker.
So I want to remove these plot point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**1**) You need to add a LimitLine

```
int maxCapacity = 100;
LimitLine ll = new LimitLine(maxCapacity, "Max Capacity");
chart.getAxisLeft().addLimitLine(ll);
```

You can also style the line by:

```
ll.setLineWidth(4f);
ll.setTextSize(12f);
```

**2**) This method may be useful:

```
chart.setViewPortOffsets(float left, float top, float right, float bottom);
```

You can read the documentation [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Modifying-the-Viewport).

**3**) This method is what you need:

```
lineDataSet.setDrawCircles(false);
```

Once again, its all available in the [documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/DataSet-classes-in-detail).

Comment: You awesome! It works! and also, 2) mChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinValue(0); is work well. Thank you.!

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin

You can use [LimitLine](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.1.0/javadoc/)

```
val limitValue = 100
val nameLimitLine = LimitLine(limitValue.toFloat(), "Limit").apply{
    enableDashedLine(10f, 15f, 0f) //For "- - - -"
    lineWidth = 2f
}
chart.axisLeft.addLimitLine(nameLimitLine)
```